# Using a ViewModel for displaying all items in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, linq-to-sql

I have a View that displays a list of entities (L2Sql), I already have a ViewModel that contains some of the properties for editing/viewing.  Is it recommended to pass an IEnumerable into the View to list all entities, or would it be prudent to pass in a list of ViewModel?

HTMS

UPDATE: Based on resopnses here is my ViewModel:

```
public class CategoryViewModel
   {
      #region Properties

      public IEnumerable<CategoryViewModel> Categories { get; set; }
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public int Order { get; set; }
      public int? ParentCategoryId { get; set; }

      #endregion
   }
```

The Categories property is used by Views for a dropdownlist, would this be acceptable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IEnumerable<ViewModel>` is the recommended way. I have seen many people defining their *view models* like this:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public SomeDomainEntity1 Entity1 { get; set; }
    public SomeDomainEntity2 Entity2 { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SomeDomainEntity3> Entities3 { get; set; }
}
```

Actually that's not proper usage of view models. That's not view models at all for me. A view model should not reference any entity domain model.

Comment: I think the nerddinner(http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part6.htm) tutorials by scottGu and co do things this way.

Comment: Before I mark as answer could you check my update?  I just want to get this right.

Comment: @raklos, hence the reason for my initial post, although I can see both sides of the story.  If you start then drilling down in your View on a closed DataContext you are in trouble, hence the need to break away from the persistence layer.

Comment: @Mantorok, your updated answer shows a perfectly valid view model. raklos, nerddinner also do things like [poor man's dependency injection](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2009/07/03/how-not-to-do-dependency-injection-in-nerddinner.aspx), so while this is a good start to learn MVC, if you want to follow best practices it is not the application I would recommend to learn from.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, sure - out of interest can you recommend where to find best practice .net MVC?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - I understand your point about keeping ViewModels separate from DomainModels.  With that in mind, what construct/layer is responsible for translating ViewModels to DomainModels (and vice versa)?

Comment: @mikemanne, the mapping layer. Personally I use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) for this task.

Comment: @raklos, *best practice* is a subjective notion.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the information from the enumerable, there's nothing wrong passing it directly to the view. If you need some extra informations (ex: current user or any other thing), you should put your enumerable as a property in your ViewModel.